# Forces from Force-Field Settings inside of Particle System do not work past Frame 100

Tags: animation, particles, hair, force-fields, cache

I am having trouble with force-fields (in the particle system itself) in that the function entirely as expected until frame 100, where they stop all force entirely and the particles go Limp. I have a cache that goes to 300 frames, and a rigid body world is also set up to 300 frames though I am sure this had no effect. I am unable to find any value for duration of force, and would assume that it is supposed to function indefinitely. How do I make this so?

Comment: please provide blend file